# CSS 'top' not pushing element down the screen

Tags: css, position

I'm trying to (almost) center a container vertically on the screen.  To do this, I'm positioning it as `relative` and using a combination of `top: 40%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`.

The trouble is, `top` isn't working (as in not pushing the container down the page), although if I inspect the element in either Firebug or Chrome I can see that the equivalent of 40% has been added to the top of the container.  If I simply click the value and press enter, the change is reflected on the page.

So my question is, why is this not working even though `top` seems to be calculated correctly?

## Here is my CSS -

```
body:not(.mobile) #login{
    padding:            0 0 40px;
    top:                40%;
    -webkit-transform:  translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:      translateY(-50%);
    transform:          translateY(-50%);
}
#login{
    position:   relative;
    z-index:    10;
}
```

## Here is how the HTML renders

```
<body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui locale-en-gb">

    <div id="login">

        { Login form goes here }

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</body>
```

## Here is a screen shot showing the issue

[image]

Comment: Can you post your completed code or provide a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS will fix it:

```
body:not(.mobile) #login{
    padding:            0 0 40px;
    top:                40%;
}
#login{
    position:   absolute;
    z-index:    10;
}
```

Edit:  You can see it working on this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7h0nz7nz/

Comment: Cheers.  I had to also use `left: 50%` and `transform:   translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);`, but it's now displaying as I would like.